# How to convert a collection of hashtables to a table within a file?

Tags: powershell

We're trying to write an `array` of ordered `hashtables` to a file. While doing this we would like to to be aligned properly in a table format. A bit similar to `Format-Table` but differently presented.

The code below works fine for the first case but not for the second one. In the second one we have a  property that is of type `array` and is incorrectly assessed. It feels a bit like we're reinventing the wheel here, is there a better solution?

Usually the values will be of type `string`, `string[]` or `boolean`, but what if another type is passed? Thanks for your help.

**Desired goals**

```bsh
Describe 'ConvertTo-TextTableHC' {
    It 'should convert a collection of hashtable to a text table' {
        $testParameters = @(
            [ordered]@{
                Name      = 'ScriptName'
                Value     = 'Get printers'
                Type      = 'String'
                Mandatory = $true
            }
            [ordered]@{
                Name      = 'PrinterName'
                Value     = ''
                Type      = 'String[]'
                Mandatory = $false
            }
        )
        $actual = ConvertTo-TextTableHC -Name $testParameters

        $expected = @"
Name        Value        Type     Mandatory
ScriptName  Get printers String   True
PrinterName              String[] False
"@
        $actual | Should -Be $expected
    }
    It 'should convert a collection of hashtable to a text table' {
        $testParameters = @(
            [ordered]@{
                Mandatory = $true
                Name      = 'ScriptName'
                Value     = 'Get printers'
                Type      = 'String'
            }
            [ordered]@{
                Mandatory = $false
                Name      = 'OU'
                Value     = @('ou1', 'ou2')
                Type      = 'String[]'
            }
        )
        $actual = ConvertTo-TextTableHC -Name $testParameters

        $expected = @"
Mandatory Name        Value        Type
True      ScriptName  Get printers String
False     OU          ou1, ou2     String[]
"@
        $actual | Should -Be $expected
    } -Tag test
}
```

This is the function:

```bsh
Function ConvertTo-TextTableHC {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary[]]$Name,
        [int]$Spacing = 1
    )

    $result = [String[]]::new($Name.Count + 1)

    foreach ($prop in $($name[0].Keys)) {
        $rows = , $prop + $Name.$prop
        $maxChars = ($rows | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum + $Spacing

        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $rows.Count; $i++) {
            $spaces = ' ' * (
                $maxChars - 
                ($rows[$i] | Measure-Object -Character).Characters
                # fails on boolean values:
                # ($rows[$i] | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum
            )
            $result[$i] += '{0}{1}' -f $rows[$i], $spaces
        }
    }

    # remove spaces from last column
    $result =  $result.ForEach({$_.Trim()})
    $result -join "`r`n"
}
```

Comment: It always hard to try to convert structured data to a flat format. The best thing at the moment is using ConvertTo-JSON. It won't be anything like what you are looking for though, as I think you are more interested in the presentation than actually storing data in a structured way?

Have you tried playing around with Custom-Format?